# QT: Unable to add select and deselect feature to listbox item in listboxwidget

Tags: c++, qt, listbox, listboxitem

I am using QT and QT Creator and compiling with it (mingw compiler for windows). I am trying to create a listbox with some mouse based functions. I have been able to add a context menu to it. Second, when I right click the contextmenu the listbox item gets selected. Third, even if I left click on the item the item gets selected. What I want to do is if an item is selected and I left click on it again, it should deselect the item in the list menu. The issue is if I write my own code, it disables the default action and the the if statement locks up the window and the window crashes. What is the logic I need to do to handle both selection and deselection methods? Seems I am doing something wrong. Here is my code. Any help is welcome.

```
#include "historicalrequests.h"
#include "ui_historicalrequests.h"
#include "customlistitemdelegate.h"

HistoricalRequests::HistoricalRequests(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::HistoricalRequests)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->historicalRequestsWidget->setItemDelegate(new CustomListItemDelegate(ui->historicalRequestsWidget));
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem();
    item->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, "Title");
    item->setData(Qt::UserRole + 1, "21/05/2017 12:12:456");
    ui->historicalRequestsWidget->addItem(item);
    QListWidgetItem *item2 = new QListWidgetItem();
    item2->setData(Qt::DisplayRole, "Workspace");
    item2->setData(Qt::UserRole + 1, "Description");
    ui->historicalRequestsWidget->addItem(item2);
    ui->historicalRequestsWidget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(ui->historicalRequestsWidget, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), SLOT(customMenuRequested(QPoint)));
}

HistoricalRequests::~HistoricalRequests()
{
    delete ui;
}

void HistoricalRequests::customMenuRequested(QPoint pos){

    // My customContextMenu click functions here

}



void HistoricalRequests::on_historicalRequestsWidget_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
if(ui->historicalRequestsWidget->item(index.row())){
    if((ui->historicalRequestsWidget->currentItem() == ui->historicalRequestsWidget->item(index.row()))){
        qWarning("Same item" );
    } else {
        qWarning("Different item");
        //ui->historicalRequestsWidget->item(index.row())->setSelected(true);
    }
} else {
    // some code here
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, all you need to do is set SelectionMode to MultiSelection:

```
ui->listWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
```

If you need to have selected only one item a time, you can handle it in slot connected to QSelectionModel::selectionChanged signal. There you can deselect previous item with selectionModel->select() method.

Comment: Ok let me try selectionModel->select() to deselect. Thanks.